# Why the triangle is not displayed using glm 0.9.9.8, but it works using glm 0.9.8.5?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math, glew

I am learning opengl and the following code is displaying a blank screen when using glm 0.9.9.8, but it works correctly using 0.9.8.5. The expected behavior is to display a triangle moving left to right.
The translation happens both way, because I print the offset.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

// Window dimensions
const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

GLuint VAO, VBO, shader, uniformModel;

bool direction = true;
float triOffset = 0.0f;
float triMaxOffset = 0.7f;
float triIncrement = 0.005f;

// Vertex Shader
static const char* vShader = "                                                  \n\
    #version 330                                                                \n\
                                                                                \n\
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;                                          \n\
    uniform mat4 model;                                                         \n\
                                                                                \n\
    void main()                                                                 \n\
    {                                                                           \n\
        gl_Position = model * vec4(0.4 * pos.x, 0.4 * pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);       \n\
    }";

// Fragment Shader
static const char* fShader = "                                                  \n\
    #version 330                                                                \n\
                                                                                \n\
    out vec4 color;                                                             \n\
                                                                                \n\
    void main()                                                                 \n\
    {                                                                           \n\
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                                       \n\
    }";

void CreateTriangle()
{
    GLfloat vertices[] = 
    {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // Lower left corner
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // Lower right corner
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f // Top corner
    };

    // Create vertex array object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    // Create vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    // Copy vertices to buffer
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Specify attribute pointer
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Unbind VBO and VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void AddShader(GLuint theProgram, const char* shaderCode, GLenum shaderType)
{
    // Create shader object
    GLuint theShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    // Create shader source
    const GLchar* theCode[1];
    theCode[0] = shaderCode;

    GLint codeLength[1];
    codeLength[0] = strlen(shaderCode);

    // Compile shader
    glShaderSource(theShader, 1, theCode, codeLength);
    glCompileShader(theShader);

    // Check for errors
    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(theShader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error compiling the %d shader: '%s'\n", shaderType, eLog);
        return;
    }

    // Attach shader to program
    glAttachShader(theProgram, theShader);
}

void CompileShaders() {
    shader = glCreateProgram();

    if (!shader) {
        printf("Error creating shader program!\n");
        return;
    }

    AddShader(shader, vShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(shader, fShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint result = 0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] = { 0 };

    // Link program
    glLinkProgram(shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error linking program: '%s'\n", eLog);
        return;
    }

    // Validate program
    glValidateProgram(shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &result);
    if (!result)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        printf("Error validating program: '%s'\n", eLog);
        return;
    }

    uniformModel = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model");
}

int main() 
{
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) 
    {
        printf("GLFW initialization failed!");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup GLFW window properties
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    // Core profile = No Backwards Compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    // Create the window
    GLFWwindow *mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!mainWindow)
    {
        printf("GLFW window creation failed!");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Get buffer size information
    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

    // Set context for GLEW to use
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    // Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("GLEW initialization failed!");
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    CreateTriangle();
    CompileShaders();

    // Loop until window closed
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow))
    {
        if (direction)
        {
            triOffset += triIncrement;
        }
        else
        {
            triOffset -= triIncrement;
        }

        if (abs(triOffset) >= triMaxOffset)
        {
            direction = !direction;
        }

        printf("%f\n", triOffset);

        // Clear window
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Color
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader);

        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(triOffset, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glUseProgram(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

I am using glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32 and glew-2.2.0-win32

Comment: glm after a certain version doesn't initialize matrices with identity (but with 0). Try `glm::mat4 model(1.0f);`

Comment: This solved it.